# Cohomology of n-sphere minus k discs

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

If $M=S_n \backslash K$, where $K$ is the union of $k\geq1$ disjoint disks $D_i$, how would you compute the de Rham cohomology of $M$?

Comment: By induction using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Comment: That's actually exactly my problem. I'm self-studying smooth manifolds, and I'm not sure I have a grasp on computations using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Comment: Start by removing points from the plane so you can see how to decompose it. Remember removing the first point from $S^2$ gives the plane.